# Parallel NMF non negative matrix factorization

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, parallel-processing

I have a large sparse matrix,2 million by 5000. I want to nmf it and i want to use parallel computations, since I have several CPUs in my server.But are there any good package for parallel nmf? I have used scikit-learn and matlab nnmf. However, the sklearn seems that does not support parallel computation. Although there is UseParallel option in matlab, when i run the code, it seems that just computes on a single CPU.

Comment: I believe that if you want `nnmf` to work in apralel in matlab you need first to start a paralel pool!

Comment: @AnderBiguri i have start a parallel pool, but it does not seem work. And the matlab memory using is much larger than sklearn n/f